# Treat a list by generating a dataframe and sending the data to function via multiprocessing

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

To collect the list with the data from an API, I need to do these steps:

```python
trading = betfairlightweight.APIClient(
    'email',
    'password',
    app_key='app_key',
    cert_files=('./certs/bf.pem'),
    session=requests.Session()
)
trading.login()

hours_limit = 12
limit_hour = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=hours_limit))

market_filter = betfairlightweight.filters.market_filter(
    event_type_ids=['1'],
    market_type_codes = [
        'MATCH_ODDS',
        'OVER_UNDER_25'
        ],
    market_start_time={
        'to': limit_hour.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    }
)

soccer_events = trading.betting.list_events(
    filter=market_filter
)
```

Output `soccer_events`:

```
[<EventResult>, <EventResult>, ...]
```

Using:

```python
def pretty_print(clas, indent=0):
    print(' ' * indent +  type(clas).__name__ +  ':')
    indent += 4
    for k,v in clas.__dict__.items():
        if '__dict__' in dir(v):
            pretty_print(v,indent)
        else:
            print(' ' * indent +  k + ': ' + str(v))
```

The output `pretty_print(soccer_events[0])`:

```
EventResult:
    elapsed_time: 0.3472568988800049
    _datetime_created: 2022-07-03 16:01:07.401756
    _datetime_updated: 2022-07-03 16:01:07.401756
    _data: {'event': {'id': '31569381', 'name': 'Bayamon FC v Puerto Rico Sol FC', 'countryCode': 'GB', 'timezone': 'GMT', 'openDate': '2022-07-03T23:30:00.000Z'}, 'marketCount': 2}
    market_count: 2
    Event:
        id: 31569381
        open_date: 2022-07-03 23:30:00
        time_zone: GMT
        country_code: GB
        name: Bayamon FC v Puerto Rico Sol FC
        venue: None
```

With this list produced I generate a *DataFrame* to handle this data:

```python
soccer_events_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'event_name': [obj_event.event.name for obj_event in soccer_events],
    'event_id': [obj_event.event.id for obj_event in soccer_events],
    'event_venue': [obj_event.event.venue for obj_event in soccer_events],
    'country_code': [obj_event.event.country_code for obj_event in soccer_events],
    'time_zone': [obj_event.event.time_zone for obj_event in soccer_events],
    'open_date': [obj_event.event.open_date for obj_event in soccer_events],
    'market_count': [obj_event.market_count for obj_event in soccer_events],
    'open_local_date': [obj_event.event.open_date.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).astimezone(tz=None) 
                        for obj_event in soccer_events]
})
```

Output:

```
                                          event_name  event_id event_venue country_code time_zone           open_date  market_count           open_local_date
0                                    FC LaPa v PKK-U  31566562        None           FI       GMT 2022-07-03 13:00:00             2 2022-07-03 10:00:00-03:00
1                          BFA Vilnius v FK Banga II  31566818        None           LT       GMT 2022-07-03 14:00:00             2 2022-07-03 11:00:00-03:00
2                            Varbergs BoIS v Varnamo  31540709        None           SE       GMT 2022-07-03 13:00:00             2 2022-07-03 10:00:00-03:00
3                    Bayamon FC v Puerto Rico Sol FC  31569381        None           GB       GMT 2022-07-03 23:30:00             2 2022-07-03 20:30:00-03:00
4                                Norrkoping v Sirius  31540708        None           SE       GMT 2022-07-03 15:30:00             2 2022-07-03 12:30:00-03:00
..                                               ...       ...         ...          ...       ...                 ...           ...                       ...
175                        Werder Bremen v Karlsruhe  31566873        None         None       GMT 2022-07-03 13:30:00             2 2022-07-03 10:30:00-03:00
176          San Martin de Formosa v CA Douglas Haig  31566616        None           AR       GMT 2022-07-03 19:00:00             2 2022-07-03 16:00:00-03:00
177  Club Defensores de P v Sarmiento de Resistencia  31566619        None           AR       GMT 2022-07-03 18:00:00             2 2022-07-03 15:00:00-03:00
178  Sportivo AC Las Parejas v CD Juventud Unida (G)  31566621        None           AR       GMT 2022-07-03 19:30:00             2 2022-07-03 16:30:00-03:00
179                          CA Liniers v Camioneros  31566623        None           AR       GMT 2022-07-03 18:00:00             2 2022-07-03 15:00:00-03:00
```

As there are many games listed, to do what I need with each of them, I need *multiprocessing*, which before starting them I go through some filters:

```python
events_bf = soccer_events_df.reset_index()
if len(events_bf) == 0:
    trading.logout()
    sys.exit()

events_bf = events_bf[events_bf['event_name'].str.contains(" v ")]
data_for_compare = (datetime.datetime.utcnow()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
events_bf = events_bf[events_bf['open_date'] >= data_for_compare]
events_bf = events_bf[events_bf['open_date'] <= limit_hour.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")]

try:
    max_process = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1 or 1
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(max_process)
    list_pool = pool.map(data_event, zip(repeat(trading), events_bf.iterrows()))
finally:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

---

This is the function used in *multiprocessing*:

```python
def data_event(event_bf) -> list:
    try:
        trading = event_bf[0]
        _, event_bf = event_bf[1]
        
        event_name = event_bf['event_name']
        event_id = event_bf['event_id']

        filter_catalog_markets = betfairlightweight.filters.market_filter(
            event_ids=[event_id],
            market_type_codes = [
                'MATCH_ODDS',
                'OVER_UNDER_25'
                ]
            )

        catalog_markets = trading.betting.list_market_catalogue(
            filter=filter_catalog_markets,
            max_results='100',
            sort='FIRST_TO_START',
            market_projection=['RUNNER_METADATA']
        )

        markets_df = pd.DataFrame({
            'market_name': [market_cat_object.market_name for market_cat_object in catalog_markets],
            'market_id': [market_cat_object.market_id for market_cat_object in catalog_markets],
            'total_matched': [market_cat_object.total_matched for market_cat_object in catalog_markets],
            'Home' : [market_cat_object.runners[0].runner_name if len(market_cat_object.runners) > 0 else '' for market_cat_object in catalog_markets],
            'Home_id' : [market_cat_object.runners[0].selection_id if len(market_cat_object.runners) > 0 else 0 for market_cat_object in catalog_markets],
            'Away' : [market_cat_object.runners[1].runner_name if len(market_cat_object.runners) > 1 else '' for market_cat_object in catalog_markets],
            'Away_id' : [market_cat_object.runners[1].selection_id if len(market_cat_object.runners) > 1 else 0 for market_cat_object in catalog_markets],
            'Draw' : [market_cat_object.runners[2].runner_name if len(market_cat_object.runners) > 2 else '' for market_cat_object in catalog_markets],
            'Draw_id' : [market_cat_object.runners[2].selection_id if len(market_cat_object.runners) > 2 else 0 for market_cat_object in catalog_markets]
        })
        
        match_odds_list = []
        Over_Under_list = []
        ids_list = []
        events_bf_markets = markets_df.reset_index()
        for index, event_bf_market in events_bf_markets.iterrows():

            if (event_bf_market['market_name'] == 'Match Odds'):
                
                order_filter = betfairlightweight.filters.ex_best_offers_overrides(
                    best_prices_depth=3
                )

                price_filter = betfairlightweight.filters.price_projection(
                    price_data=['EX_BEST_OFFERS'],
                    ex_best_offers_overrides=order_filter
                )
                
                market_books = trading.betting.list_market_book(
                    market_ids=[event_bf_market['market_id']],
                    price_projection=price_filter
                )

                runners = market_books[0].runners
                
                back = []
                try:
                    back.append([runner_book.last_price_traded
                                            if runner_book.last_price_traded
                                            else '-'
                                            for runner_book
                                            in runners])
                except:
                    back.append(['-',"-"])

                match_start = event_bf['open_date']
                match_start_2 = pd.to_datetime(str(match_start))
                match_odds_list.append(match_start_2.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'))
                match_start_local = event_bf['open_local_date']
                match_start_local_2 = pd.to_datetime(str(match_start_local))
                match_odds_list.append(match_start_local_2.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'))
                match_odds_list.append(event_bf_market['Home'] + ' v ' + event_bf_market['Away'])
                match_odds_list.append(event_bf_market['Home'])
                match_odds_list.append(event_bf_market['Away'])
                match_odds_list.append(back[0][0])
                match_odds_list.append(back[0][1])
                match_odds_list.append(back[0][2])
                ids_list.append(event_bf_market['Home_id'])
                ids_list.append(event_bf_market['Away_id'])
                ids_list.append(event_id)

            elif (event_bf_market['market_name'] == 'Over/Under 2.5 Goals'):
                
                order_filter = betfairlightweight.filters.ex_best_offers_overrides(
                    best_prices_depth=3
                )

                price_filter = betfairlightweight.filters.price_projection(
                    price_data=['EX_BEST_OFFERS'],
                    ex_best_offers_overrides=order_filter
                )
                
                market_books = trading.betting.list_market_book(
                    market_ids=[event_bf_market['market_id']],
                    price_projection=price_filter
                )

                runners = market_books[0].runners
                
                back = []
                try:
                    back.append([runner_book.last_price_traded
                                            if runner_book.last_price_traded
                                            else '-'
                                            for runner_book
                                            in runners])
                except:
                    back.append(['-'])
                
                Over_Under_list.append(back[0][0])
                Over_Under_list.append(back[0][1])

        if (len(match_odds_list) >= 1):
            return match_odds_list + Over_Under_list + ids_list
        else:
            return ['off']

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)        
        return ['off']
```

I would like a review on the methods used to treat this list as well as so many list comprehensions together to be able to generate the *DataFrame* and if the *multiprocessing* model I'm using is really the most appropriate for such data type.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Hi @pacmaninbw I understand, but it wouldn't make sense create a new question just to show the object's string that I had forgotten to show, I didn't change the code., for sure I would receive several downvotes on the new question.

Comment: Which is why I didn't rollback the edit. Just try not to edit your posts after they have answers in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need multiprocessing

Do you actually? What is the runtime like with and without it? How many rows are you processing? If this takes (say) less than a second with a reasonable Pandas implementation and no parallel processing, I'd call the added complexity of the multiprocessing call to potentially be a higher cost than the benefit. Perhaps it's necessary due to the `list_market_catalogue` inner API call.

The field types of `EventResult` are unclear. Hopefully `obj_event.event.open_date` is a real datetime and not a string. If it is a string, you need to be telling Pandas to parse that to a datetime.

This is not a good idea:

```
data_for_compare = (datetime.datetime.utcnow()).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

as you should not be comparing strings when they're actually dates. Again, if `open_date` has been properly parsed, then you will be comparing datetimes directly instead of as strings.

This:

```
for index, event_bf_market in events_bf_markets.iterrows():
```

doesn't take enough advantage of Pandas vectorisation. For instance, within that loop, this `if`:

```
        if (event_bf_market['market_name'] == 'Match Odds'):
```

can be split out so that you select that subframe in a vectorised manner, as in

```
match_odds = event_bf_market[event_bf_market.market_name == 'Match Odds']
# ... operate on this subframe unconditionally
```

`data_event` is too long. You should pull out some subroutines. It's also incomplete in its typehints: `event_bf` needs a type, and `list` needs a `list[contained type]`.

You call out

> so many list comprehensions together to be able to generate the DataFrame

and are right to do so. A certain amount of looping is inevitable because your target leaves are at different depths of the `obj_event` tree. Consider instead one loop that builds up an intermediate list of flat dictionaries and then call [DataFrame.from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_records).

Comment: about the formats that are delivered, I added example to ```obj_event``` in the question.